# Where does Kyoko get those delicious looking apples?

Tags: madoka-magica

In the show, we always see Kyoko with some sort of food, but we never see where or how she obtains these foodstuffs.

Where does she get those bags of apples from? Is it related to her powers some how (e.g. did she create them with her powers or use her powers to steal them)?

[image: Where does she get them?]

[image: Mmm apples!]

Comment: Kyubey said that Sayaka heals so fast because her wish was for healing. So since Kyoko's wish is to have people hear for whatever her dad says, my assumption is she tricked people to give that food.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conversation between Kyoko and Sayaka in the church strongly implies that Kyoko does in fact steal the apples and that she knows that it's wrong.

The dead give-away for this is towards the end of the conversation. (ep 7, roughly 13:45 including OP)

- Sayaka asks Kyoko where she got the apples. Where she got the money from.
- Kyoko looks down at the apple and flinches. She does not answer.
- Kyoko then lashes out at Sayaka in apparent defense of her actions.

That's exactly the kind of reaction someone would get when they are caught doing something 
illegal/criminal.

---

In short, episode 7 paints a dark picture of Kyoko and her past. She's basically in "survival mode". So even though she knows that stealing is wrong, she still needs to eat. Without money or any other support, her only option is to steal and make the most of what she has. This is also why she gets angry at Sayaka when Sayaka throws the apple on the ground calling it a "waste".